# C# Prime Numbers with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, primes

I am interested with LINQ these days. I am trying to get prime numbers. I am actually did very well but my code doesn't show primes which is below Sqrt(n).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Func<int, int, IEnumerable<int>> EnumerableRange =
            (startPoint, endPoint) =>
                Enumerable.Range(Math.Min(startPoint, endPoint), Math.Abs(startPoint - endPoint) + 1);

        Func<int, int, bool> isFullyDivided =
            (value, divisor) =>
                (value % divisor).Equals(0);

        int sp = 2,
            ep = 100;

        var query =
            EnumerableRange(sp, ep)
            .Where(value =>
                EnumerableRange(2, (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(ep)))
                .Any(divisor =>
                    isFullyDivided(value, divisor))
                    );

        var primeNumbers =
            EnumerableRange(sp, ep)
            .Except(query);

        foreach (var item in primeNumbers)
        {
            Console
                .WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console
            .Read();

    }
```

Currently, this code incorrect leaves out the prime numbers that are less than `sqrt(n)`.  The code is supposed to get the primes between 2 and 100.  Instead it only prints prime numbers 11 and above. The primes `2, 3, 5, 7` are missing.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how your code is not working?

Comment: Following code presents prime numbers 11 and  above. Below 11 which are 2, 3, 5, 7 is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You constraint of divisors is incorrect - you are looking at divisors between 2 and `Sqrt(ep)` (10), when you only need to check divisors between 2 and `Sqrt(value)`:

```
    var query =
        EnumerableRange(sp, ep)
        .Where(value =>                                      V----------
            EnumerableRange(2, (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(value)))
            .Any(divisor =>
                isFullyDivided(value, divisor))
                );
```

That is why your primes start at 11, because your divisors go up to 10 which would include the value itself.  @ryanyuyu's answer also solves the same problem but in a different way.  Your code will still be checking unnecessary divisors.

Comment: @ryanyuyu's answer is correct. I am missing that condition.
!value.Equals(divisor)

Comment: You don't _need_ that condition if you change your divisor selection.

Comment: True - you still need the condition using your method, but I still contend that you can reduce the range of divisors.  You're doing unnecessary comparisons once you go over `Sqrt(value)`  Most prime number generators add 2 and 3 explicitly and then loop from 2 to `Floor(Sqrt(n))`

Comment: Thank you too with Sqrt(value) it is faster.

Comment: This is a good improvement to reduce the number of needed comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You have a logic problem.  Everything can evenly divide itself, so you should check that the `value != divisor`.  Otherwise you will incorrectly exclude the numbers that divide themselves (for example `5 % 5 == 0`).

```
var query =
    EnumerableRange(sp, ep)
    .Where(value =>
        EnumerableRange(2, (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(ep)))
        .Any(divisor =>
             value != divisor &&  //This is the logic you are missing
             isFullyDivided(value, divisor))
            );
```

Comment: Thanks. Really thanks. I am thinking like hours like "what am i missing ? damn." Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution :

```
            var query =
            EnumerableRange(sp, ep)
            .Where(value =>
                EnumerableRange(2, (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(value)))
                .Any(divisor =>
                    !value.Equals(divisor) &&
                    isFullyDivided(value, divisor))
                    );
```

Math.Floor is wrong. Correct one is Math.Ceiling.